# how to find the current date in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am finding trouble in retrieving the current date in my XSLT code. I am using version 1.0  and MSXSL.exe application to trigger my xslt code. 
I tried using the following line of code to implement this functionality, however its not working. Looks like the version 1.0 doesn't support the current date function. Could you please provide a solution which will work for xslt 1.0.

```
               <xsl:value of select="current-date()"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no current-date() function in XSLT 1.0.

If your processor supports it, you can use the date-time() EXSLT extension function. Otherwise
you will have to pass the date as a parameter to the stylesheet during runtime, or get it from a web service.

Comment: msxsl.exe abc.xml xyz.xslt o final.xml

Comment: I am using the following line in the command prompt to create my output xml file - 'final.xml' :

msxsl.exe abc.xml xyz.xslt o final.xml

Should i be using :



msxsl.exe abc.xml xyz.xslt o final.xml con vDate='%date%'

Answer (score 2):

With MSXML you can use extension functions done in JScript or VBScript, see http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/index.html for details and an implementation http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/date-time/date.msxsl.xsl which should work with MSXML.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the date by passing the %date% argument in command prompt. Could you please let me know how can i format my date 
in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format