# XSLT transformation datetime

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i need to do datetime transformation in xslt,EffectiveDate should be the next day of current date and ExpirationDate should be EffectiveDate + one year Can you please help me

input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Name>Test</Name>
</root>
```

output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<EffectiveDate>2017-05-4 13:05:658+0200</EffectiveDate>
<ExpirationDate>2018-05-4 13:05:658+0200</ExpirationDate>
</root>
```

sample xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <EffectiveDate></EffectiveDate>
            <ExpirationDate></ExpirationDate>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the current date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627949/how-to-find-the-current-date-in-xslt-1-0/26628225#26628225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on you XSLT processor, but you can solve this problem using a script.  This example uses C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Web" />
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Web" />
    <![CDATA[
          public string GetDate(string DateFormat)
          {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);
          }

          public string GetExpirationDate(string DateFormat)
          {
            return DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString(DateFormat);
          }

        ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <EffectiveDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="user:GetDate('dddd, dd MMMM yyyy')"/>
      </EffectiveDate>
      <ExpirationDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="user:GetExpirationDate('dddd, dd MMMM yyyy')"/>
      </ExpirationDate>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```