# How to get all child element from node

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to extract the child element from XML with all values and their elements

Child:node() :- Return no result
child::*- This get the value of first element

Sample XML

```
<testdata>
 <Name>
  <Name1>Rahul</Name1>
  <Name2>Rahul</Name2>
  <Name3>Rahul</Name3>
  <Name4>Rahul</Name4>
  <Name5>Rahul</Name5>
  <Name6>Rahul</Name6>
  <Name>
<testdata>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:Util="urn:Util" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs msxsl xsl Util">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="testdata">
<DummyallMane>
<xsl:value-of select="//testdata/name/child::node()
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected result

```
<Name1>Rahul</Name1>
<Name2>Rahul</Name2>
<Name3>Rahul</Name3>
<Name4>Rahul</Name4>
<Name5>Rahul</Name5>
```

Comment: I tried most the Xpath what i get on google but no luck

Comment: Try using `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`. In XSLT 1.0,  `xsl:value-of` returns only the value of the first node in the selected node-set. And it doesn't copy markup.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using `xsl:value-of`, which only returns the text value of a node. You should be using `xsl:copy-of` here to copy the nodes themselves.

Also, in XSLT 1.0, if you use `xsl:value-of` on multiple nodes, it will only return the value of the first one (which is why `child:*` only returns the first when used in `xsl:value-of`). Note that `child::node()` returns nothing, as `node()` also selects text nodes, and so it will pick up the white space node before the `Name1`. (If you had added `xsl:strip-space` to your node, you would have then got results).

So, you should be doing this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Name/*" />
```

(Also note that XSLT is case-sensitive, so `name` would not actually select `Name`)

See it working here... http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeZ

Note, I am assuming `Name6` should be in your expected results too. But if you did actually want to exclude the last node, you could do this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Name/*[position() != last()]" />
```

Or this, to exclude a node with a given name

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Name/*[not(self::Name6)]" />
```

Comment: when i tried in my editor i get the expected result but i get one line space in each elements.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "one line space in each element" I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question for you, is there any way to get a year in XSL?  I tried many ways but fail.

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0, then there is no built-in way. You would have to use an extension function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627949/how-to-find-the-current-date-in-xslt-1-0