# Add current date and time using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

when I am trying to get current date and time as below ,I get an error "Error in XPath expression Unknown function-Name and number of arguments do not match any function signature in the static context-'http://exslt.org/dates-and-times:date-time' .Is there any other way I can get currentdatetime in xslt 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">
   ----
         <test>
          <xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/>
          </test>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not all processors support all EXSLT extension functions. Which processor are you trying to use?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627949/how-to-find-the-current-date-in-xslt-1-0 for alternatives.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -I am using altova XMLSpy

Comment: I believe that's an IDE, not an XSLT processor. See how to identify the processor here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033